# How do you pass a PartitionKey to Execute a StoredProcedure?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure on a partitioned collection (server side partitioning) from the .net SDK (v1.6.3).

`await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("db0", "collection0", "testsproc0"), storedProcedureParams);`

I receive the error "PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation". In fact, I see this error in the Azure Portal when I play around with the Script Explorer. However, I see no way to add a PartitionKey. Is this a limitation with the API and partitioned collections right now, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can pass in the partition key by using the overloaded ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync method with RequestOptions.  For example,

```
await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<DeviceSignal>(
UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("db", "coll", "SetLatestStateAcrossReadings"),
new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("XMS-001") }, sprocsParams);
```

Comment: I definitely think you are right because this is what is in their docs, but unfortunately I'm still getting the error. I think there is an issue because I set a Partition Key, on a single-partition collection.

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving a similar error and found that I had an incorrect `Partition Key Path` when I created the document collection as shown in the line, `collectionDefinition.PartitionKey.Paths.Add("/LastName")`, below. My ExecuteStoredProcedure RequestOption didn't match the field that I selected in the `new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("matchingLastNameSelectionHere") }`. Hope this helps.

```
        private static async Task<DocumentCollection> CreateCollectionAsync(string dbLink, string id)
    {
        DocumentCollection collectionDefinition = new DocumentCollection { Id = id };
        collectionDefinition.IndexingPolicy = new IndexingPolicy(new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 });
        collectionDefinition.PartitionKey.Paths.Add("/LastName");

        return await _client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
            dbLink,
            collectionDefinition,
            new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 400 });
    }
```

Execute code

```
await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<DeviceSignal>(UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("db", "coll", "SetLatestStateAcrossReadings"), new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("matchingLastNameSelectionHere") }, sprocsParams);
```

Comment: how to do using pydocumnetdb client (python client ) only single method available  client.ExecuteStoredProcedure()